# Scan subset of PD DataFrame to obtain indices matching certain values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. Some of the columns should have only 0s or 1s. I need to find the columns that have a number other than 0 or 1 and remove that entire row from the original dataset.

I have created a second data frame consisting of the columns that must be checked. After finding the indices and dropping them from the original data frame, I am not getting the right answer.

```py
#Reading in the data:
data=pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv')

#Creating subset df of the columns that must be only 0 or 1 (which is all rows in columns 2 onwards:
subset = data.iloc[:,2:]

#find indices:
index = subset[ (subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)].index

#remove rows from orig data set:
data = data.drop(index)
```

It is giving me an empty index array. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Can you give a small example of input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'D':[1,0,1,0,1,0],
         'E':[1,0,0,1,2,4],

})

print (data)
   A  B  D  E
0  a  4  1  1
1  b  5  0  0
2  c  4  1  0
3  d  5  0  1
4  e  5  1  2
5  f  4  0  4
```

If need only `1` and `0` values use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all `True`s per rows:

```
subset = data.iloc[:,2:]
data3 = data[subset.isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]
print (data3)

   A  B  D  E
0  a  4  1  1
1  b  5  0  0
2  c  4  1  0
3  d  5  0  1
```

**Details**:

```
print (subset.isin([0,1]))
      D      E
0  True   True
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True   True
4  True  False
5  True  False

print (subset.isin([0,1]).all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I need some help. After you called "data1", shouldnt you have seen the final answer? I dont understand why you are seeing rows 0 and 1

Comment: @JohnSpencer - Yes, exactly. Another solution removed.

Comment: @JohnSpencer - Maybe my problem is not understand what is problem, can you explain more?

Comment: I emailed you my code + .CSV file! Would you please please take the time to look it over?

Answer (score 1):

Your `subset` is a pd.DataFrame, not a pd.Series. The conditional testing you are doing for `index` would work if `subset` were a Series (i.e. if you were only checking the condition on a single column, not multiple columns).

So having `subset` as a DataFrame is fine, but it changes how the conditional slice works. My testing shows your `index` var returns NaN for 0s and 1s, (rather than leaving them out like a slice of a Series would). Adding dropna() as below should fix your code:

```
#find indices:
index = subset[ (subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)].dropna().index

#remove rows from orig data set:
data = data.drop(index)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but man it is not working!! I am so frustrated. It is keeping the rows with values like 11 or 10 or something! Is there anyway I can post my csv data file?

Answer (score 1):

Without your data from `DataSet.csv`, I tried to make a guess.

`subset[ (subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)]` basically returns the `subset` dataframe with  values `False` on `(subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)` turning to `NaN` while those `True` keeping same values. I.e. this is equivalent to `map`. It is not a filter.

Therefore, `subset[ (subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)].index` is the whole index of your `data` dataframe

You drop it, so it returns empty dataframe

Comment: Can I email you my .CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

From you code I made a calculated guess that you want to compare for `more than 1` columns.

This should do the trick

```
# Selects only elements that are 0 or 1
val = np.isin(subset, np.array([0, 1]))

# Generate index
index = np.prod(val, axis=1) > 0

# Select only desired columns
data = data[index]
```

Example

```
# Data
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  1  3
3  4  3  3
4  5  3  1

# Removing rows that have elements other than 1 or 2
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
```