# Removing certain Rows from subset of df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. All the columns right of column#2 may only contain the value 0 or 1. If they contain a value that is NOT 0 or 1, I want to remove that entire row from the dataframe.

So I created a subset of the dataframe to only contain columns right of #2
Then I found the indices of the rows that had values other than 0 or 1 and deleted it from the original dataframe.

See code below please

```py
#reading data file:
data=pd.read_csv('MyData.csv')

#all the columns right of column#2 may only contain the value 0 or 1. So "prod" is a subset of the data df containing these columns:

prod = data.iloc[:,2:]
index_prod = prod[ (prod!= 0) & (prod!= 1)].dropna().index
data = data.drop(index_prod)
```

However when I run this, the index_prod vector is empty and so does not drop anything at all.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56269228/2901002

Comment: How can I provide sample data? I would love to share my .CSV file. How can I do this?

Comment: a copy paste of the first few rows can serve as a decent substitute instead of the entire file. Alternatively, you loaded it into a dataframe, a sample df can work just fine too.

Comment: We are not asking for a whole dataset (be aware of information sensitive). You can provide just some example of data: columns and rows

Comment: ZipCode CustomerAge SamsungTV46LED SonyTV42LED XBOX360 DellLaptop BoseSoundSystem
30134 35 1 1 1 0 0
62791 43 0 1 0 0 1
60611 23 1  0 1 0
60616 56 0 1 1 1 0
30303 25 1  0  1
2108 55 1 1 1 1 10

Comment: @John Could you please edit your question and include examples?

Comment: @JohnSpencer dont write the same problem twice https://stackoverflow.com/q/56269228/2901002

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scan subset of PD DataFrame to obtain indices matching certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269228/scan-subset-of-pd-dataframe-to-obtain-indices-matching-certain-values)

Comment: okay so my friend just told me that the data is not numeric and he fixed it by making it numeric. Can anyone please advise how I can find that out? Because all the columns were numeric it seemed like to me. All numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> okay so my friend just told me that the data is not numeric and he fixed it by making it numeric. Can anyone please advise how I can find that out? Because all the columns were numeric it seemed like to me. All numbers

You can check dtypes by [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html).

```
print (data.dtypes)
```

Or:

```
print (data.columns.difference(data.select_dtypes(np.number).columns))
```

And then convert all values without first 2 to numeric:

```
data.iloc[:,2:] = data.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Or all columns:

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

And last apply solution:

```
subset = data.iloc[:,2:]
data1 = data[subset.isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this dataframe:

```
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [0, 1, 4, 3, 1], 'C': [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   A  B  C
0  1  0  2
1  2  1  1
2  3  4  0
3  4  3  3
4  5  1  4
```

And you want to delete rows based on column **B** that don't contain **0 or 1**, we could accomplish by:

```
subset = df.iloc[:,1:]
index = subset[ (subset!= 0) & (subset!= 1)].dropna().index

df.drop(index)
   A  B  C
0  1  0  2
1  2  1  1
4  5  1  4

df.reset_index(drop=True)
   A  B  C
0  1  0  2
1  2  1  1
2  5  1  4
```